# StyleCop 4.7 minor bug with Rule SA1518

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, stylecop

I'm experiencing a minor problem with `StyleCop 4.7`:

it doesn't catch the violation `SA1518(CodeMustNotContainBlankLinesAtEndOfFile)` when there is a blank line right after the last curly bracket in the code.

If there is a space in the blank line, then the violation is shown. When there is more than one blank line at the end of the file, the violation is shown too.

Perhaps someone has experienced the same issue and has a workaround for it?

```
namespace Namespace
{
     public class MyClass()
     {
     }
}
<- doesn't show the violation

namespace Namespace
{
     public class MyClass()
     {
     }
}
 <- shows the violation
```

Comment: As a workaround, there is a StyleCop plugin called StyleCop+ which seems can handle that in a way you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Style rule is :

```
namespace Namespace
{
     public class MyClass()
     {
     }
}
<- is not a "violation"

namespace Namespace
{
     public class MyClass()
     {
     }
}
 <- is a "violation"

namespace Namespace
{
     public class MyClass()
     {
     }
}

<- is a "violation"
```

If you want to ignore this harsh error in style then you can use :

```
[SuppressMessage("StyleCop.CSharp.LayoutRules", "SA1518:CodeMustNotContainBlankLinesAtEndOfFile", Justification = "Reviewed.")]
```

However it does not make a functional difference and therefore I would classify it as :

**not a real problem**.

Answer (score 0):

This related with ReSharper;

Resharper-> Options-> Code Editing -> C# -> Formatting Style -> Blank Lines -> Around Namespace

This way you can increase or decrease value.